# Bayesian network network problem

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, bayesian-network

[image: Image since I can't embed yet (not enough rep)]

I want to find:

$P(C=0,A=1,D=1)$.

---

I know the following:

$P(C=0,A=1,D=1) = P(C=0|A=1, D=1)*P(A=1|D=1)*P(D=1)$

From the image, we can see $P(D=1)$ is $P(D=1) = P(D=1|A=0)*P(A=0) + P(D=1|A=1)*P(A=1) = 0 + 0.7 * 0.9 = 0.63$

I also know $P(A=1|D=1)=\dfrac{P(D=1|A=1)P(A=1)}{P(D=1)}=\dfrac{0.7*0.9}{0.63}=1$

So our answer is:

$P(C=0|A=1,D=1)*0.63$

I don't know how to calculate the first part.

I think it's $\dfrac{P(C=0,A=1,D=1)}{P(A=1,D=1)}$, but the numerator is just the entire question again and denominator we are not given.

My textbook says answer should be $0.3024$

Answer (score 1):

You have $\lower{1ex}D\raise{1ex}{\swarrow \raise{2ex}A\searrow}\lower{1ex}{ B\lower{2ex}{\searrow\lower{2ex} C}}$ and wish to find $\def\P{\operatorname{\mathsf P}}\P(C^0, A^1, D^1)$, a shorthand for $\P(C{=}0,A{=}1,D{=}1)$.

The goal is to expand this out into terms whose values may be read off the tables.

Well, $A$ is root, and $C,D$ are leaves of separate branches, so condition over $A=1$, then expand out the branch for $C=0$.

$$\begin{align}\P(C^0, A^1, D^1)&=\P(A^1,D^1,C^0)\\[1ex]&=\P(A^1)\P(D^1\mid A^1)\P(C^0\mid A^1)\\[1ex]&=\P(A^1)\P(D^1\mid A^1)\big(\P(C^0\mid B^0)\P(B^0\mid A^1)+\P(C^0\mid B^1)\P(B^1\mid A^1)\big)\end{align}$$

---

$$\small\P(C{=}0,A{=}1,D{=}1)=\P(A{=}1)\P(D{=}1\mid A{=}1)\big(\P(C{=}0\mid B{=}0)\P(B{=}0\mid A{=}1)+\P(C{=}0\mid B{=}1)\P(B{=}1\mid A{=}1)\big)$$

Comment: However it seems $C=0$ is not given on the graph, so it has probability $0$. Thus the right most equation all has probability $0$, and this would overall give a value of $0$

Comment: We can assume the Random Variables are either $1$ or $0$

Comment: Yes, complements are found the usual way: $\mathsf P(C{=}0\mid B{=}1)=1-\mathsf P(C{=}1\mid B{=}1)=0.3$

Comment: Do the same rules apply if we are dealing with 4 variables? 

For example, would $P(A^1,B^0,C^1,D^0)=P(A^1)P(B^0|A^1)P(D^0|A^1)P^(C^1|A^1)$, where $P(C^1|A^1)=P(C^1|B^0)P(B^0|A^1)+P(C^1|B^1)P(B^1|A^1)$?

Comment: Yes but...  If you already have a bridge between A and C just use it. $P(A^1)P(B^0\mid A^1)P(C^0\mid B^0)P(D^0\mid A^1)$

Comment: We have a bridge yes, but that is for $C=0$ and here I am asked for $C=1$, how can we still use it?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  clearly:$$\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}}\P(A^1,B^0,C^1,D^0)=\P(A^1)\P(B^0\mid A^1)\P(C^1\mid B^0)\P(D^0\mid A^1)$$

Comment: Thank you for the extra help Graham. I understand. Cheers! I'll be sure to accept answer when I get enough rep